# How to use cbp2make in linux?

Tags: makefile, codeblocks

I dowmloaded cbp2make.
I read some comments and saw that I have to copy the executable of cpb2make to /usr/bin/. I tried to copy with no success. Then I install it by yum install cbp2make, but when I try to write the basic xommand of cbp2make I got error which said that this command not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed cbp2make with yum and did not get any error messages, it  should be somewhere in your system.

I installed cbp2make with `sudo apt install cbp2make` in linux mint Sarah and by typing `whereis cbp2make`, I see that it is in /usr/bin/.

You can type `echo $PATH` to see what is in your path. If your path does not contain the folder where cbp2make lies, then you can edit the file at ~/.bashrc and put this in it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/PATH_TO_YOUR_CBP2MAKE
```